# Convert character strings to variable name

Tags: r

Is there a command/other way to get the value of a variable that is identical to a character string?

For instance, in the code below I would like to be able to get the value `2`    from the call `letters[2]`, because the second element of `letters` (`"b"`) is the "same" as the variable name `b`.

```
b <- 2

letters[2]

[1] "b"
```

Is there a command that does this? Apologies if this has been asked before, I'm new to R.

Comment: `get(letters[2])`. Why do you need this? This seems to by xy problem

Comment: [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/974/)

Comment: Thanks, that works. There most definitely will be a better solution to my problem, but I'm just trying to get something to work and I'm neither a programmer nor developer or any sort of PC wizard, so any ugly solution is fine by me as long as it does the job.

Comment: Happy to help, best luck with your work